# Next Auth getSession API call fails when used in getServerSideProps function on production

Tags: next.js, session-cookies, server-side-rendering, next-auth

`getSession` is working fine in Client side but not in Server side

When it is called in Server Side I get this error on server:

> error -> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error session FetchError: request to https://nextauth_url_internal/api/auth/session failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND nextauth_url_internal

Server Side Code

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { req } = context;
  try {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    console.log({ session });
    if (!session) return { redirect: { destination: '/', permanent: false } };
    return { props: { session } };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: NEXTAUTH_URL is already set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you didn't configure the [NEXTAUTH_URL environment variable](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#nextauth_url).

Comment: NEXTAUTH_URL is already set to website domain.

Comment: Are you sure it's correct, look at the url next-auth is trying to fetch (bold) :  request to https:// **nextauth_url_internal** /api/auth/session failed

Comment: Yeah it's correct that is why session API was fetched successfully on the client

Comment: Can you provide example of your NEXTAUTH_URL variable

Comment: I was missing some configuration in my deployment pipeline

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Vercel, any ideas?

Comment: did you figure this out? same issue with Vercel @AhmedSarhan

Answer (score 1):

can you try this: delete the .next build folder and create a new build by running `npm run build`.

and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem on my backend. At last I found out that `NEXTAUTH_URL` must be set for the backend, too, and it might be different from frontend URL when running backend in the Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Add a secret option in your NextAuth function

```
export default NextAuth({
   // Configure one or more authentication providers
   providers: [
      GoogleProvider({
         clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
         clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      }),
      // ...add more providers here
   ],
   secret: process.env.SECRET,
   pages: {
      signIn: "/auth/signin",
   },
   callbacks: {
      async session({ session, token, user }) {
         session.user.username = session.user.name
            .split(" ")
            .join("-")
            .toLocaleLowerCase();

         session.user.uid = token.sub;
         return session;
      },
   },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the exact same issue, it turns out I didn't set my env correctly.
I used different "OAuth App" on GitHub for "development" and "production".
Ensure your local env and production env correspond to the right GitHub OAuth App. (GITHUB_ID,GITHUB_SECRET,NEXTAUTH_URL)
Make sure that callback_URL on the OAuth app is the same as NEXTAUTH_URL.
And also you need a "secret" env variable for production, but not necessarily for local since it will automatically generate for you on development.